# knife vsphere vm clone - hangs on "waiting for sshd ..."

Tags: chef-infra, knife, vsphere

I am having an issue trying to get passed the following line

```
"Waiting for sshd .........."
```

When running a "vm clone" command for a Windows Server 2012 R2 core template.

Has anybody had this issue?

If so, what do I need to do to resolve it as I have been trying things for the past day.

Please note that the template already has "winrm" up and running.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately that looks hardcoded: https://github.com/ezrapagel/knife-vsphere/blob/master/lib/chef/knife/vsphere_vm_clone.rb#L293-L294

It wants to find a port for SSH that is up and accepting connections. That said, the "ssh_port" is configurable so you could just set that to the port used for WinRM instead.